# ScrollView/ListView does not respond to my finger gesture

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to be able to scroll through a list using my finger on the screen, but right now I need to use the track ball at the bottom of the phone. Is there something that I need to implement or something that I am doing wrong? Here is my XML with the ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height="250dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_height="250dip"></ListView>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_user_names" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And below is from my class:

The list is populated using this method:

```
private void populateList(){
String[] projection = new String[]{NameProviderMetaData.NameTableMetaData._ID,      NameProviderMetaData.NameTableMetaData.NAME};
Cursor c = managedQuery(NAMES_URI,projection,null,null,NameProviderMetaData.NameTableMetaData.NAME);
String[] cols = new String[] {NameProviderMetaData.NameTableMetaData.NAME};
int[] views = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
adapter = new     SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,c,cols,views);
setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I have an onTouchEvent method elsewhere in the class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
    return true;
    else
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a ListView inside a ScrollView (any two views that have same orientation scrolling). You should reconsider your layout!

You could do this for example:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_height="250dip" android:background="@null"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"></ListView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_user_names" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sweet! That works! Is there a way to keep the background from changing to black during the scroll?

Comment: No problem at all! Thank you too!

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using the listview inside scrollview add layout dynamically using inflater. and GestureDetector not work perfectly in vertical scrollview. I figure out swipe code for scrollview

> http://www.techin.info/2011/11/swipe-event-in-android-scrollview.html (cancelled)

updated link  : http://techin-android.blogspot.com/2011/11/swipe-event-in-android-scrollview.html

Comment: @ud_dan: above link seems to be expired!